# How can I copy Whatsapp data on Blustacks to my new PC

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluestacks

I have bought a new laptop because I'm travelling to another province(state) and I will be there for 6 months and I can't leave with my PC. I want to know how can I copy the contacts and messages from Whatsapp on my Blustacks from my PC.

Answer (score 2):

**Contacts:**

Sync them with google

**Conversations:**

Your WhatsApp messages are automatically backed up and saved on your phone's memory daily. If you delete WhatsApp from your phone and don't want to lose any of your messages, be sure to manually back up your chats before uninstalling:

```
Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat Settings
Tap Backup Conversations
```

To export a copy of the history of an individual chat or group, you can use the Email Chat History feature:

```
Tap and hold on the conversation or group.
Select Email conversation
Choose whether to Attach Media or not.
```

An email will be composed with your chat history attached as a .txt document.

If you choose to attach media, the most recent media sent will be added as attachments.

Comment: Ruben I get that. The problem is both of my whatsapp are on my PC. I use whatsapp through Bluestack App Player on my PC.

Comment: The easiest way is to install a cloud storage client app like dropbox and sync the `/sdcard/Whatsapp` folder where the conversations are backed up.